# NSURLConnection methods no more available in IOS5

Tags: nsurlconnection, ios5

I was looking at the `NSURLConnection` class which could be used to establish a sync or async connection to an URL and then retrieve its data... a lot of changes have been made to this class with IOS 5 and I've seen they introduced some formal protocols related to authentication  or download, but I don't see, for example, if the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` message (that was previously sent to the delegate and that it is no more available) is still available in some protocols.. How do you implement an async connection and retrieve, for example, HTTP headers as soon as the Response is received? I'm sure there is a way better than using `NSURLConnection` along with the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` message.. methods like `stringWithContentsOfURL` do always load content synchronously? What do you use to implement async downloads in your apps avoiding deprecated methods and reacting to events such as _http response received_m etc ? Do you launch synchronous downloads in background tasks, if possible?

Comment: As is, your question should be split into multiple questions: there are potentially five questions inside your question. My answer addresses what I perceive to be your biggest issue, namely the apparent removal of the connection delegate methods that were available in iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`NSURLConnectionDelegate` has become a formal protocol (it was an informal protocol in previous versions). In this protocol, the following (non-deprecated) methods are declared:

- `connection:didFailWithError:`
- `connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:`
- `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`

Furthermore, there are two subprotocols that conform to `NSURLConnectionDelegate`:

`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` is used for delegates that load data to memory, and declares the following methods, some of which I’m sure you’ll find familiar:

- `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`
- `connection:didReceiveResponse:`
- `connection:didReceiveData:`
- `connection:needNewBodyStream:`
- `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`
- `connection:willCacheResponse:`
- `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

`NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` is used for delegates that store data directly to a disk file, and declares the following methods:

- `connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:`
- `connectionDidResumeDownloading:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:`
- `connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:`

As you can see, you can still use your previous delegates, possibly with some minor modifications.

For more information, see the [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Differences document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/) and NSURLConnection.h in your local Xcode installation. When a new SDK version is released, it’s not uncommon for the documentation inside the header files to be more reliable than the documentation available on the developer library. It takes a while for the latter to be up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you... I've just seen that reference docs have not been updated yet, so the API difference doc and the header file is a good starting point.. I thought I've seen somewhere (I can not find it now..) that docs say that usually your apps should not implement NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol... tell me if I'm wrong: if you need to implement a sort of download progress bar, shouldn't you use the didReceiveData to understand when you've downloaded a bit of data or did I misunderstood how didReceiveData works and when it is sent?

Comment: @Gianni Yes, `-…didReceiveData:` is sent to the delegate to notify that data have been received. Besides storing those data, you can use it to update a download progress bar.

Comment: FYI, as of 04/08/12, the 5.1 SDK documentation still does not have a complete reference on NSURLConnectionDataDelegate (neither online nor within the SDK).

Comment: GRRRR! As of 3/9/2013 the NSURLConnection Class Reference STILL has no reference to anything about NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. If not for this question I'd still be searching. Here is Apple's doc on this protocol: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: "NSURLConnectionDelegate has become a formal protocol ..." Do you mean "NSURLConnectionDataDelegate", or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this same issue. Looks like sending an asynchronous request is more simplified with blocks and `NSOperationQueue`.

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

This means that the delegate is now only used for authentication and failure issues.

Comment: Thank you, I could not find it in the reference docs, maybe it will be soon updated.

Comment: Normally it is now updated. Watch out however, because this method is not available on iOS 4.3. In summary: you will need to implement both ways to be compatible with iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

NO!
They are NOT limited to use for authentication and failure issues if you look carefully through the Apple's library.

Since introducing `+(void)sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` to NSConnection class object, Many things which can perform as many `NSConnectionDelegate` method as before can now be used in formal protocols called "`NSConnectionDataDelegate`" & `NSConnectionDownloadDelegate`, opening a new room to add more feature to `NSURLConnection` methods. (from iOS5 on)

So I think it is an improvement, not limiting their use.

Answer (score -1):

Even I havent found the documentation on the Apple website

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

It should have been available over here