# Why is Apple's documentation of NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol reference seemingly missing stuff?

Tags: objective-c, ios

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate

Just wondering why this protocol reference doesn't include information on methods like "didReceiveData", "connectionDidFinishLoading" ? etc.

Are they deprecated or something?  They don't come up in autocomplete anymore either.

Is there a new way you are supposed to receive and append the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLConnection methods no more available in IOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803472/nsurlconnection-methods-no-more-available-in-ios5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're in the protocol `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. In earlier versions of iOS they were in an informal protocol, but since iOS 5 they were in the new `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Yes, you can find more information in this answer to a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7901893/1207152