# NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method is not calling

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsurlconnection

Im trying to implement `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol's methods, but there is one method, named `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`, that do not want to be called by delegate. [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) do not give enough information about it, so I have no idea how to use it. Any help with this method would be useful for me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:

Comment: @janusfidel: The documentation is misleading in this point. `connection:didSendBodyData:...` has only been moved to the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol. It can still be used and I know of no replacement. See e.g. the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803472/nsurlconnection-methods-no-more-available-in-ios5.

Comment: I saw this discussion. It is not giving the answer how to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

I was porting some obj-c code to Swift and could not get the didSendBodyData method to be called. It ended up being that my method signature was not quite right. Make sure that your method matches the API exactly. In swift it looks like this:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didSendBodyData bytesWritten: Int, totalBytesWritten: Int, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int) {
    // Update the progressbar
    println("didSendBodyData")
}
```

Hope this helps the next guy (or gal).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NSURLConnection` with a POST request to upload data to the http server, then the `connection:didSendBodyData:...` delegate method is called regularly to inform you about the upload progress.